# Why logs are empty after logging.config.dictConfig(...)?

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

*Original title was "How to find a problen in python logging configuration?"*

I have quite a large project with a lot of loggers. I have wrapper to run project and it has some logging confid. Everything works nice.

Then I made another wrapper to serve project as cherrypy and noticed that I have logging problem.

I fight a lot with settings but did not get any other logs to be printed to file.

Here is my logging config for cherrypy wrapper.

```
{
        'formatters': {
            'standard': {
                'format': '%(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'b2_debug': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'filename': 'b2_debug.log',
                'maxBytes': 1048576,
                'backupCount': 20,
                'encoding': 'utf8'
            },
            'cherrypy_access': {
                # same as b2_debug, but another filename]
            },
            'cherrypy_error': {
                # same as b2_debug, but another filename]
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['b2_debug'],
                'level': 'DEBUG'
            },
            'cherrypy.access': {
                'handlers': ['cherrypy_access'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': False
            },
            'cherrypy.error': {
                'handlers': ['cherrypy_error'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': False
            },
        }
}
```

I have a lot of active loggers but under cherrypy somehow `b2_debug.log` is empty.

Two questions:

1. How can I debug logger behavior? Are there any tool that can trace movement of event when i execute `logging.getLogger('test').warn('test')`?
2. Any idea what can cause root `''` logger not to log anything? Looks like something overrides root logger behaviour.

I have tested on simple one-file and everything works. But I don't know how to find problem with extremely big project.

Comment: You are using a relative path name. Try an absolute path. It may be writing the log, but jsut in a different place than you think. You could break into a debugger just before a log statement and step through it to see where it goes. Exactly how you do that varies with environment. A simple `breakpoint()` may do it if you are on the same machine. I searched "debug cherrypy" and got some interesting hits. When you get to the point of the file being written, the file object's `name` attribute plus `os.path.abspath` will be a good clue.

Comment: Are you sure that you're testing the application with logging level DEBUG? Otherwise that debug handler is never going to log anything.

Comment: @cyraxjoe Yes, but also i use warnings and critcal levels

Answer (score 2):

**There is `disable_existing_loggers` parameter that is `True` by default. I changed it to `False` and everything works now.**

Just added it as additional config dict key `'disable_existing_loggers': True,`.

Important note: that I use `logging.config.dictConfig(DICT)`. And this is the  point I made every `logger.disabled = True`

Thanks to @tdelaney for reminding me about breakpoint. It was quite simple to find a problem. I noticed that python checks logger.isEnabledFor() and somehow it is disabled. I've remembered that is saw something like that in docs. That helps!